# Powershell. New-ScheduledTaskAction. The Count parameter recognised in one statement but not another

Tags: powershell, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to schedule a Powershell task, part of which tests for internet connectivity at regular intervals and sends the output to a file. The 'Count' parameter for the 'Test-Connection' cmdlet is being accepted as a standalone statement, but when transplanted into a New-ScheduledTaskAction and assigned to a variable the 'Count' parameter is not recognised.

This works:

```
Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Count 2 -Quiet | 
ForEach-Object {  "$(Get-Date -Format "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]") $_" } | 
Out-File -Append -FilePath C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\internet-log.txt
```

But when transferred to:

```
$InternetConnectionLog=New-ScheduledTaskAction 
-Execute "powershell.exe" 
-Argument Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Count 2 -Quiet | 
ForEach-Object {  "$(Get-Date -Format "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]") $_" } | 
Out-File -Append -FilePath C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\internet-log.txt
```

I'm presented with:

```
New-ScheduledTaskAction : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Count'.
At line:1 char:108
+ ... ute "powershell.exe" -Argument Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Count 2 -Quie ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ScheduledTaskAction], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,New-ScheduledTaskAction
```

The resulting error message points specifically to the 'Count' parameter being the problem. What precisely is preventing the same parameter from being recognised?

Comment: You should try enclosing your argument value with single quotes.

Comment: Use `-Argument 'Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Count 2 -Quiet | ForEach-Object {  "$(Get-Date -Format "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]") $_" } | Out-File -Append -FilePath C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\internet-log.txt'` with no line breaks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. That eliminated the error message and allowed me to progress to register a scheduled task. However,  Get-ScheduledTaskInfo indicates that although the task is running every 60 seconds it return a Last Task Result of '1'. Nothing is written to file, nor is it evident that the Test-Connection cmdlet is being run, as specified by the Argument of the New-ScheduledTaskAction. When I run that exact Argument alone it works as intended.

Comment: @AdminOfThings: I encourage you to write your comment up as an answer, along with an explanation of why doing it this way is necessary. user2962912: Once AdminOfThings has done so, you should accept that answer. Your follow-up question should be asked as a _new question_.

Comment: @mklement0 - should I accept the answer and ask a new question if the answer offers a partial solution?

Comment: The proposed answer would address your fundamental misconception about the required _syntax_, which is the part of your question potentially of interest to future readers. Any follow-up problems that arise after the syntax problem has been corrected are unrelated, and best addressed separately.

Comment: @mklement0 - The error message went away, but the statement does not work within the scheduled task. All the other elements of the scheduled task work. That suggests that the required syntax of the statement has yet to be supplied.

Comment: @user2962912: No, that suggests a _semantic_ problem with the particulars of your command (I haven't looked into it), not a _syntax_ problem - hence the need to separate. Whatever follow-up problems there may be, the point is that your question betrays a fundamental misconception about the syntax requirements, which is worth addressing first and foremost.

Answer (score 1):

The `-Argument` parameter of `New-ScheduledTaskAction` expects a string to be passed to it. Enclosing your parameter value in quotes makes PowerShell interpret it as a string.

```
$InternetConnectionLog = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument 'Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Count 2 -Quiet | 
   ForEach-Object { 
      "$(Get-Date -Format "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]") $_" 
   } | Out-File -Append -FilePath C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\internet-log.txt'
```

The reason for single quotes over double quotes here is to preserve the string as is, which is called a literal string. Everything within single quotes tells PowerShell to not perform variable expansion. You can use double quotes, which will require escaping PowerShell's special characters that you want to literally pass like `$` and `"` in your case. Another alternative is to store your argument value in a variable as a string (still using single quotes). Then just pass the variable to the `-Argument` parameter.

Through simpler examples, you can see the described behavior:

```
$a = "I am a string"
$a.gettype().name
String

$b = "What am I? $a"
$b
What am I? I am a string

$c = 'What am I? $a'
$c
What am I? $a

$d = 'I want to keep my "double quotes" and $dollars$.'
$d
I want to keep my "double quotes" and $dollars$.
```

See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) for further explanation about string expansion and using both types of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from AdminOfThings eliminated the error message. I was able to to register the statement as a scheduled task.